# Why OpenMP program runs only in one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I just tried OpenMP with a simple c program

```
test() {
   for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++);
}
main() {
    printf("Num of CPU: %d\n", omp_get_num_procs());
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) test();
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -fopenmp`. It can correctly print out that I have 4 CPUs, but all test functions are running at `thread 0`.

I tried to modify the `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. But it has no effect also.

I had everything the same as the online examples but why wouldn't I get it to work?

Comment: How do you know that it runs only one thread?

Comment: Yes I checked in the test() by printing out the omp_get_thread_num().

Comment: Did you check `omp_get_max_threads()` to see if openmp things that it can use only one thread for some reason?

Comment: Thanks, I checked omp_get_max_threads() in the test() and it is 4. But still every test() runs on thread number 0.

Comment: Is it possible that the compiler optimizes out all of the loops as they don't do anything, and then each thread finishes quicker than the loop creating them can run as they don't do anything... so there is only ever one thread running. Just a theory, probably wrong :)

Comment: Try `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(4)`. Static scheduling is the de facto default but not necessarily the default.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is here:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_thread(4) <---
```

The correct clause is `num_threads(4)`, not `num_thread(4)`. Incorrect openmp pragmas are ignored and so you ended up with a sequential program. :)

I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler warning, because I did.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, that was a typo. In the code I had it num_threads(4) but still have no luck

Comment: @Eines He: Then it's very strange, because I pasted your code, compiled it and ran it and it worked on all 4 cores.

Comment: How do you set up your environment? I think the code is quite basic and could not possibly go wrong. I am using g++ 4.6.1 and libomp1. I think the openmp is definitely working because I have no problem in checking the number of cpus ...etc. It must be some where I didn't set the environment correctly.

Comment: Hmm... I tested this on Windows with cl.exe. I'll test it on my Linux environment ASAP and let you know.

Comment: Ok, so I tested on ubuntu with g++ 4.5.2 and it also works fine there.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in visual studio and finally I understood that I had forgotten to enable Open MP support in visual studio. It didn't give me any error but executed the program just for one thread

Comment: http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/getting-started-with-openmp-on-visual-studio/

Comment: Saved my time. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

first choose project _> properties -> c/c++ -> language -> open mp support -> choose yes 
and then you will find above conformance mode (make it no )

Answer (score 0):

use the function omp_set_num_threads(4) before calling the omp parallel section.

also, how do you determine the number of threads ?? 
embed your printfs in a critical section just to make sure everything is getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the very same situation on my ubuntu desktop when I extends numpy module with C code. openmp only ran with one thread. I happened to remove libopenblas-base and install libatlas-base-dev.(to deal with numpy installation problem) Then multi-threading openmp came back:)

I have tested it on a ubuntu server with 64 cores and it works just as my desktop!
I think this is because libopenblas conflicts with libraries like atlas.