# How to configure ImageMagick to be faster? (commandline SVG to PNG Conversion)

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, converters

I'm using PHP's `exec` function to execute the command `convert` on my server.

For a 6,7 kB SVG-File (converted file: 5,2 kB PNG-File) the following command:

```
/usr/bin/convert -density 72 -resize 270 80 -background transparent
  /var/www/app/img/logo.svg PNG32:/tmp/svg2png/20140105-
  a86b2ed2c38ed310020d201db8042d71.png
```

Takes about 0,0001s on my MBP but about ~15 sec on my six-core Server.
How is this possible? Are there any settings for ImageMagick that could be the issue?

I already decreased density with no effect.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-bench` & `-verbose` options to troubleshoot what's not performing well. Performance issue with SVG delegates have been known, but have been addressed in recent years. Ensure that [imagemagick](/questions/tagged/imagemagick) is up-to-date on your server, and that all configured features & delegates are set-up correctly.

```sh
identify -list configure
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17755692/438117) about [openmp](/questions/tagged/openmp) slowing down the `convert` utility on Debian / Ubuntu systems.